# Make my JavaScript run after SharePoint JavaScript

Tags: javascript, 2003

In SP 2003 how can I make sure my JavaScript is the absolute last script to be run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do a JavaScript timer to make your code execute a specific number of milliseconds after the page loads (like 500ms).